# Verticaly center windows with gtk API

Tags: gtk

It is possible with the help of gtk API to position one window under another centered in the middle

```
  ------------------
  |   WINDOW TOP   |
  ------------------


----------------------
|    WINDOW BOTTOM    |
----------------------
```

I try:

```
GtkAllocation alloc;
gint x, y;

gtk_window_get_position (WINDOW_TOP, &x, &y);
gtk_widget_get_allocated_size (WINDOW_TOP, &alloc, NULL);

gtk_window_move (WINDOW BOTTOM, alloc.x + x, alloc.y + alloc.height + y);
```

but windows are left aligned.

Comment: The answer completely depends on the window manager you're targeting. Windows? Wayland/X on Linux? MacOS?

Comment: Wayland on Linux. Thanks

Comment: Should it not be that the `x` takes into account the width of the windows?